# Android AnimatedVectorDrawable - Property: is not supported for FullPath

Tags: android, android-animation, android-support-library

I have this specific error using Android AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat:

Exception: `Property: scaleX is not supported for FullPath`

- Using android support lib: `27.0.2`
- Android Nougat SDK

But the same animation is working for older OS versions.

**Animation**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="54dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:viewportHeight="2.0"
        android:viewportWidth="54.0">

    <!-- Green Line -->
    <path
        android:name="line_green"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 54,0 Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="@color/green_color"
        android:strokeWidth="2"/>

</vector>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Android Nougat and support lib 27.0.x there are changes in how AnimatedVectorsDrawable works and you need to put your item vectors inside a group and set the "name" to the group and remove it from the path so the animations are applied to the group.

```
    <!-- Green Line -->
    <group
        android:name="line_green"
        android:strokeAlpha="0">
        <path
            android:pathData="M 0,0 L 54,0 Z"
            android:strokeColor="@color/green_color"
            android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    </group>
```

I found the solution in this github thread: https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/issues/132